# Error handling in UpdatePanel with <CustomErrors mode="On" />

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have custom errors enabled in my web.config file:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx" />
```

When an error happens during an asynchronous postback in an UpdatePanel, the response comes back as a code 200 and the content set as the error page.

This breaks when the UpdatePanel tries to parse the response and throws a JavaScript exception:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   message received from the server could not be parsed.

Is there a way to properly handle this on the client side without having to disable the custom error, as I do not want to divulge any exception details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to wire up the `OnAsyncPostBackError` event on your `ScriptManager` control:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="False"
    OnAsyncPostBackError="ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError" />
```

This [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbackerror.aspx) has a full example using this method to handle async postback errors.

**EDIT**
To get around the issue with the custom error pages be sure to set the `AllowCustomErrorsRedirect` property on the `ScriptManager` to `false`. Once I set this property to false I was able to get the MSDN sample to work properly even though I had CustomErrors mode="On" set in the web.config.

Comment: If am already doing something similar, however this approach is based on `if (... args.get_error().httpStatusCode == '500')` which does not work when custom errors are enabled, since it will always return a code 200. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @Xavier, OK, think I got it now. Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Also, one thing to note about this approach is that it does return a 200 response (checked with Fiddler), but in the response text (at least for the MSDN sample) you'll see "46|error|500|Value does not fall within the expected range.|", which indicates the 500 error.

Comment: This is perfect. I found that it would always return a code 500 and only include the error message when custom errors are off (or RemoteOnly and you are testing locally), which is ideal. Thanks for researching (and finding!) this.